# .NET and MySql paramters, AddWithValue NULL variables, how to avoid to check for nulls

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, null

Let's say I have a MySql stored procedure that inserts a record with some nullable CHAR fields.

In VB.NET if I don't check for Nothing (or Null in other languages), I get an exception from the db driver, so I write:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", if(name Is Nothing, "", name)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

And this is the first thing I don't like; I'd like to pass Nothing and the driver knows it has to put NULL in the Db. But then, in the stored procedure, I have to check back the field if it is empty:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(
    name,
-- other 200 char fields
)
VALUES
(
    NULLIF(_name, ''),
-- other 200 char fields
)
```

Ugly uh? I have to check for nothingness/emptiness twice. 
Is there a better, more direct, way?

Even worse, for non reference types (i.e: Integers) the check for nothingness makes no sense, since a primitive type can't be nothing (yes, I could set an Integer to a non meaningful value, say -1 for a positive id, but...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbNull.Value doesn't solve the problem, the exception is thrown if you don't specify that the parameter **is nullable**.

```
Dim par As New MySqlParameter("p1", Nothing)
par.IsNullable = True
par.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32 ' or any other type you need '
par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
command.Parameters.Add(par)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This way it works. I don't have to check for the empty string (or weird "impossible" value) in the SP.

Of course you can write a shared generic method to easy the parameter setting, working for any database/language type:

```
Public Shared Function GetNullableSqlParameter(Of T As IComparable)(ByVal parameterName As String, ByVal parameterType As MySqlDbType, ByVal value As T, Optional ByVal nonNullable As T = Nothing) As MySqlParameter

        Dim par As New MySqlParameter
        par.ParameterName = parameterName
        par.MySqlDbType = parameterType
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        If value Is Nothing OrElse (nonNullable IsNot Nothing AndAlso nonNullable.Equals(value)) Then
            par.IsNullable = True
            par.Value = DBNull.Value
            par.SourceColumnNullMapping = True
        Else
            par.IsNullable = False
            par.Value = value
        End If

        Return par
    End Function
```

And call it like:

```
command.Parameters.Add(General.GetNullableSqlParameter("_zip", MySqlDbType.String, zipcode))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use next if you want to insert `NULL`:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", name ?? DBNull.Value);
```

means the same as

```
if(name != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", name);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", DBNull.Value);
```

See more about null-coalescing operator on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

And if you want to insert empty char `''` you next:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", name ?? '');
```

Comment: useful, but not in VB, only C#. and it doesn't solve the conversion in the SP.

Comment: I've tried, but at least with CHAR fields, DBNull.Value can't be set: the db driver raises an exception.

Comment: @vulkanino: right, C#, your post wasn't tagged with `vb.net` and C# syntax used. Anyway in VB.NET you can use `If(name, DBNull.Value)`

Comment: @vulkanino: What version of MySQL .NET connector are you using? The latest is `6.3.4`. Try to upgrade

Comment: I'm using 6.3.4 already, the DBNull thing doesn't work, please read my own answer below, it works like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DbNull.Value` instead of the empty string.